# Is there any way to configure tomcat servlet working directory?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

When I'm running my web-application in tomcat and of course it's classes having tomcat working directory, because the JWM was started there. But is there any way to configure tomcat, as all classes of each deployed application, will have the application directory as their working directory?

Comment: So what it is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee I've edited question: I need that my application class have the application folder as it's working directory, not the tomcat start folder.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to configure Tomcat working directory. You can get your application root directory from your servlet by calling :

```
 String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

Note that this folder is accessible from client browser.

If you want a working directory that is inaccessible from client, create a folder inside WEB-INF

```
 String privateRoot = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF");
```

Comment: Yes, I can get absolute path for my app, but I'm trying to configure log4j. So, I'm searching a way, where I can set up local path for logs and be sure that on any configuration of container, the logs will be stored inside my application directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can change Tomcat's startup scripts. The tomcat process inherits whatever the current directory was for the startup script. To make tomcat start in a different working directory, you'll have to figure out what is launching tomcat, and change that process to change to the desired directory before it runs startup.sh.

You can look [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html) on how to setup the working directory.

Comment: This is good, **but** it is only change the **tomcat** WD, so I'll have same WD for tomcat and _all_ my webapps, which is of course simply reachable through launching tomcat from different directory. And I'm searching way to configure a **webapp** WD, independenetly of other apps and tomcat (only depending on webapps root).